# Getting the sum of a category in a specific month in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, time, sum

I am trying to get the sum of all categories from a certain month from my transactions table in my sqlite database. Here is how the table is set up...

| id | transactionDate | transactionAmount | transactionCategory | transactionAccount |

Now, I want to specify three things:

1. The account name
2. The month
3. The year

And get the sum of the transactionAmount grouped by transactionCategory from the specified account, year, and month.

Here is what my SELECT statement looks like...

`SELECT SUM(transactionAmount) AS total, transactionDate, transactionCategory
FROM transactions
WHERE transactionAccount=? AND Strftime(\"%m\", transactionDate)=? AND Strftime(\"%y\", transactionDate)=?
GROUP BY transactionCategory ORDER BY transactionCategory`

Unfortunately, this returns zero rows. I am able to get accurate results if I don't try and select the month and year, but I would like to see the data from specific ranges of time...

Comment: What is the format of the dates in the database?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that comment. It's in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Like 2013-01-11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was simply formatting the year incorrectly. It should have been strftime('%Y', transactionDate)=? NOT strftime('%y', transactionDate)=? - the difference being a capital Y vs. a lowercase one.